# Docker Desktop will not start

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am helping a co-worker who had his Docker Desktop app just stop working about a week ago.  When he tries to run it he gets this error:

> The system cannot find the file C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe

It is really confusing, because that is the exact file we are running!  It is there!  Even when we run `Docker Desktop.exe` from a command line in the `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker` folder, it still gives the same error (saying it cannot find the file).  But clearly the file is there!

(Note that this is **NOT** the same error you get when you try to run a non-existant file.  That would be `'filenamehere.exe' not recognized as an internal or external command`)

Things we have tried:

1. Reboot
2. Uninstall and re-install Docker Desktop
3. Turn off and then turn back on the Docker Windows Service.
4. Move C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin to the top of the PATH environment variable.
5. Add C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker to the PATH environment variable (and move it to the top).
6. Checked to see if `Docker Desktop.exe` is a symlink that has its target missing. (Via `dir /al /s`)

I just can't think of anything else that would cause this kind of error.

What can we do to fix Docker Desktop?

Comment: Delete docker desktop, install WSL2, install ubuntu, enable systemd, install docker directly in ubuntu using `curl get.docker.com|bash`. You now have docker and you don't have to play around with all that windows nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL 2) not being excepted from the virus checker.  Once that was done, reinstalled and rebooted, it all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause that error is if the EXE relies on a DLL that is no longer there (either directly, or at the end of a long chain of dependencies).

You can check this by doing [a dependency walk](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the EXE to see if that's the case.

Comment: I gave that a go and it did not really show any dependencies (on my machine that is running Docker Desktop just fine).

Comment: @Vaccano, doing it on the working machine is unlikely to find a problem, suggest you do it on the machine that's *not* working.